# flex box order not working when resizing window

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to fix the sidebars for my webpage. i have made a homepage where everything works swimmingly, and i'm trying to recreate the same layout for a new page except i'm using scripts to get the sidebars. the homepage doesn't use any scripts and has all the css and parts of the page (ex:sidebars) in the index file, but i'm working to create a version of my layout that separates the parts and uses scripts to call them in.

the issue is that when i resize the new page, the order of the flexbox suddenly stops working. this isn't an issue on the homepage, but it's an issue on this new page i'm working on that uses scripts.

[homepage regular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rykr0.png)
[homepage resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXEYj.png)

[new page regular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3avAM.png)
[new page resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpFa0.png)

i would like to make the new page resize properly as shown above, following the order that i've set in my css so that my page is responsive on mobile. any help would be greatly appreciated.

**new page html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>welcome to the ricebowl</title>
  <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#header").load("/header.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#leftSidebar").load("/ls.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#rightSidebar").load("/rs.html"); 
    });
    </script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="topBar"><marquee>SITE UNDER CONSTRUCTUMALATIONS. SITE UNDER CONSTRUCTUMALATIONS. SITE UNDER CONSTRUCTUMALATIONS.</marquee></div>
<div id="header" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"> </div>
  <div id="flex;">
    <aside>
     <div id="leftSidebar"></div>
    </aside>
      <main>
        <h1>writing masterlist</h1>
        <p><strong><i>a collection of works</i></strong></p>

        <img src="/blinkies/seadiv.png" style="width:100%;">

        <p>my disdain for online indicators, notifications, and read receipts </p>
        <p>on romance, as an anti-romantic hopeless romantic </p>
        <p>the commercialization of art </p>
      </main>
    <aside>
      <div id="rightSidebar"></div>
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
          <footer id="footer" style="margin-top: 10px; font-size: 11px;">footer</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
    :root {
      --header-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a4/1d/07/a41d079e7d36f6b70a1e56c8b7e97e71.jpg');
      --body-bg-image: url(https://sadhost.neocities.org/images/tiles/water2.webp);
      /* colors */
      --content: #06B4B2;
    }
    
    @font-face {
      font-family: DM Mono;
      src: url('/fonts/DMMono-Regular.ttf') format("truetype");
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: DM Mono;
      src: url('/fonts/DMMono-Medium.ttf') format("truetype");
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: DM Mono;
      src: url('/fonts/DMMono-Italic.ttf') format("truetype");
      font-style: italic;
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: DM Mono;
      src: url('/fonts/DMMono-MediumItalic.ttf') format("truetype");
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: Caprasimo;
      src: url('/fonts/Caprasimo-Regular.ttf') format("truetype");
    }

    body {
      font-family: 'DM Mono', monospace;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #06B4B2;
      background-size: 65px;
      color: #FAF8EE;
      background-image: var(--body-bg-image);
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #container {
      max-width: 900px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #container a {
      color: #71FFFC;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    #container a:hover {
      color: #06B4B2;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    #header {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #06B4B2;
      height: 150px;
      background-image: var(--header-image);
      background-size: 100%;
    }

    #navbar {
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #13092D;
      /* navbar color */
      width: 100%;
    }

    #navbar ul {
      display: flex;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    #navbar li {
      padding-top: 10px;
    }

    /* navigation links*/
    #navbar li a {
      color: #ED64F5;
      /* navbar text color */
      font-weight: 800;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    #navbar li a:hover {
      color: #a49cba;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #flex {
      display: flex;
    }

    aside {
      background-color: transparent;
      width: 200px;
      padding: 0px;
      font-size: smaller;
    }

    main {
      background-color: #0C5172;
      border-radius: 10px;
      flex: 1;
      order: 2;
      padding: 20px;
}
    #leftSidebar {
      order: 1;
    }

    #rightSidebar {
      order: 3;
    }
    
    footer {
      background-color: #061236;
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    h1,
    h2,
    h3 {
      color: #2FE4EB;
      font-family: 'Caprasimo'
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 25px;
    }

    strong {
      color: #2FE4EB;
    }

    hr.dashed {
      border: none;
      border-top: 2px dashed #2FE4EB;
    }

    .box {
      background-color: #061236;
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: 1px dashed #2CEAF2;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .sbbox {
      background-color: #0C3172;
      border: 3px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    /* CSS for extras */
     #topBar {
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: smaller;
      background-color: #061236;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      #flex {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }

      aside {
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      main {
        order: 1;
      }

      #leftSidebar {
        order: 2;
      }

      #rightSidebar {
        order: 3;
      }

      #navbar ul {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you must have changed the HTML structure for the new page, as this shouldn't work on the homepage. Flex works only on child elements and your sidebars (the `div`s with the `id`) are grandchildren, so `order` has no effect. There is also an erroneous semicolon in `<div id="flex;">` but most modern browsers are forgiving.

```
<div id="flex;">
  <aside>
   <div id="leftSidebar"></div>
  </aside>
    <main>
      <h1></h1>
      <p></p>
    </main>
  <aside>
    <div id="rightSidebar"></div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

I suspect that you will get the intended result if you were to do away with the nested `div`s and give the `id` to `aside`.

```
<div id="flex">
  <aside id="leftSidebar"></aside>
  <main>
    <h1></h1>
    <p></p>
  </main>
  <aside id="rightSidebar"></aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your solution, but it didn't seem to do anything...layout still remains strange. Anything I should check?

Comment: @lettuce It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.

Comment: good news, after trying to make a live demo i somehow managed to find the problem and fix it. thank you very much for your help!